# Matplotlib don't show the correct vector

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, vector, visualization

I'm new to python and learn to plot graph with matplotlib.
I try to plot vector that point from **(0, 0)** to **(2, 1)**.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

O = [0, 0]
V = [2, 1]

plt.quiver(O[0], O[1], V[0], V[1], units='xy', scale=1, color='r')

plt.xlim(-3, 3)
plt.ylim(-3, 3)

plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

**My vector plot :**
[image: my vector plot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should specify also the parameters:

- `angles = 'xy'`
- `scale_units = 'xy'`

Read the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.quiver.html) for more information on those parameters.

Full line of code:

```
plt.quiver(O[0], O[1], V[0], V[1], units = 'xy', angles = 'xy', scale = 1, scale_units = 'xy', color = 'r')
```

[image]